# How to extract adjacent strings from txt file with multiple conditions using awk?

Tags: regex, awk

I have this txt file

```
[23/10/10 14:37:44:527 EST]  DEBUG
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Request session="lkjh" id=12321>
<type>Old</type>
</Request>
[23/10/10 15:37:44:527 EST]  DEBUG
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Request session="lkjhab" id=432>
<type>New</type>
</Request>
[23/10/10 16:37:44:527 EST]  DEBUG
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response session="lkjh" id=12321>
<type>Old</type>
</Response>
```

I need to use awk to get all requests and responses that have id=12321 AND type "Old".I've never used awk before and i can't find a way to get adjacent strings to the string with id.

The only way i managed to get multiple lines was with grep but only with one pattern.

```
$ grep id=12321 file.txt -B2 -A2
[23/10/10 14:37:44:527 EST]  DEBUG
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Request session="lkjh" id=12321>
<type>Old</type>
</Request>
--
[23/10/10 16:37:44:527 EST]  DEBUG
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response session="lkjh" id=12321>
<type>Old</type>
</Response>
```

But with grep i can't get requests and responses that have BOTH id=12321 AND type "Old".

Maybe i'm taking wrong approach? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Awk is definitely a better tool for this particular task, but what you are asking should be fairly trivial. What did you search for, and what did you find? What did you try, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `gnu-awk` you can set `RS` variable to `</Request>` or `</Response>` as record separator and then check for 2 search terms in `$0`:

```bash
awk -v RS='</Re(quest|sponse)>' '/id=12321/ && /<type>Old/ {print $0 RT}' file

[23/10/10 14:37:44:527 EST]  DEBUG
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Request session="lkjh" id=12321>
<type>Old</type>
</Request>

[23/10/10 16:37:44:527 EST]  DEBUG
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response session="lkjh" id=12321>
<type>Old</type>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this, with a proper `xml` parser: [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel):

```
$ xidel -s --input-format=text file.txt -e '
    for $x in tokenize($raw,"\[.+\]  DEBUG")[.]
    return parse-xml($x)[./*[@id=12321 and type="Old"]]
' --output-node-format=xml --output-node-indent
```

Credits to [Reino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75626750/how-to-extract-adjacent-strings-from-txt-file-with-multiple-conditions-using-awk/75626901?noredirect=1#comment133431771_75626901)

##### Output

```
<Request session="lkjh" id="12321">
  <type>Old</type>
</Request>
<Response session="lkjh" id="12321">
  <type>Old</type>
</Response>
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your needs?

Comment: The impulse to use a proper XML parser is a good one, but hitting the file system with one small file for each extracted fragment is somewhat unattractive.

Comment: Not sure I agree, think of re-usability an readability

Comment: Anyway, the way I understood the requirement was that they want the whole file when the conditions match.

Comment: Yes, that's why I tell I probably misunderstood. There's some days like this where you have not sufficient sleep ^^

Comment: `xidel -s --input-format=text "input.txt" -e 'for $x in tokenize($raw,"\[.+\]  DEBUG")[.] return parse-xml($x)[./*[@id=12321 and type="Old"]]' --output-node-format=xml --output-node-indent` ;)

Comment: Reino to the rescue, thanks! Post edited accordingly. Fascinating tool `xidel`, I try to learn from it as a daily basis

Comment: Just a FYI: Normally `--input-format=text` isn't needed to process simple text, but in this case it is needed, because if an input starts with `[` or `{`, then Xidel assumes `--input-format=json`.

Answer (score 1):

A common solution is to set the record separator `RS` to something which uniquely identifies a new record, so that the current record in each iteration consists of all the lines you want to examine (one entry or related sequence; your target "thing"). Your test data didn't contain any literal square brackets so this is a simple demonstration which works for your sample data:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { RS="[" } NR>1 && /id=12321/ && /<type>Old<\/type>/ { print "[" $0 }' <<\:
> [23/10/10 14:37:44:527 EST]  DEBUG
> <?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
> <Request session="lkjh" id=12321>
> <type>Old</type>
> </Request>
> [23/10/10 15:37:44:527 EST]  DEBUG
> <?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
> <Request session="lkjhab" id=432>
> <type>New</type>
> </Request>
> [23/10/10 16:37:44:527 EST]  DEBUG
> <?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
> <Response session="lkjh" id=12321>
> <type>Old</type>
> </Response>
> :
[23/10/10 14:37:44:527 EST]  DEBUG
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Request session="lkjh" id=12321>
<type>Old</type>
</Request>

[23/10/10 16:37:44:527 EST]  DEBUG
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response session="lkjh" id=12321>
<type>Old</type>
</Response>
```

If you need to accommodate literal square brackets in the data as well, you might perhaps sacrifice the separator line (the one with the square brackets and the DEBUG) and use a regex which uses the entire line as the separator; but that then means that the contents of that line will be discarded as a separator, and not included in the output. (You'll notice that my code above adds back the `[` which was "eaten" as a separator.)

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples in any version of `awk` please try following code. Written and tested with shown samples Only.

```
awk '
/^\[[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}/{
  if(flag2){
    print value
  }
  flag1=flag2=value=""
}
{
  value=(value?value ORS:"") $0
}
/ id=12321>/{
  flag1=1
  next
}
/<type>Old<\/type>/ && flag1{
  flag2=1
}
END{
  if(flag2){
    print value
  }
}
'   Input_file
```